# Android refresh data using observable in recyclerview automatically with the data I get from api

Tags: android, kotlin, observable

I am trying to build an Android app using Coingecko API. I have a coin detail page. The page shows a variable named current price. The user sees the coin price with this data. And, I want to refresh this data when it is changed or every 5 seconds-10 seconds, etc. But, I do not want to use Handler or something similar. I want to do this by using Observable in kotlin. How can I do that? Please help me. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: You want to create a background task, hit the api as often as you want, then pass that data to a Flow. Then subscribe to that Flow from your UI. Follow something like this: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow#collect then come back to stackoverflow with some code when you are stuck :-)